# Learning read-once branching programs with membership queries

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

Let $B=\{0,1\}$. A **read-once branching program** of width $n$ and size $w$ is given by a graph with layers $0,\ldots, n$, where the first layer has just the starting node, the last layer has nodes labeled 0 and 1, each layer has $\le w$ nodes, and each node has 2 edges labeled 0 and 1 pointing to nodes in the next layer. To evaluate the program on $x_1\ldots x_n$, simply start at the start node and follow the edges labeled $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, and read the label on the last node. Fix $n$, and let $w$-ROBP be the class of width $w$ read-once branching programs (and by abuse of notation, the functions computed by them).

**Question:**

Find an $\text{poly}(n,\epsilon)$ algorithm (or else show it would break some hardness assumption) such that given $f:B^n\to B$ as a black box, it computes $g\in w$-ROBP with high probability such that

$$
\mathbb{P}_{x\sim B^n}(g(x)\ne f(x))\le \min_{h\in w\text{-ROBP}} \mathbb{P}_{x\sim B^n}(h(x)\ne f(x)) + \epsilon.
$$

In other words, find an agnostic PAC-learning algorithm for $w$-ROBP.
Even a weaker bound depending on $\min_{h\in w\text{-ROBP}} \mathbb{P}_x(h(x)\ne f(x))$ would be interesting. I'm convinced that I have an algorithm for when $f\in w$-ROBP (so that the max is 0) but it doesn't generalize to this setting.

A quick literature search shows intractability results for more powerful classes such as [width 3 (read-many) branching programs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=225342), and learning algorithms for finite automata (which are ROBP's with each layer the same), and not much on ROBP's. I would also appreciate any other results/references on learning for ROBP's.

Comment: It might help you to know that read once branching programs are also called "OBDD" in some of the literature. A google search for OBDD learning comes up with some results that seem relevant.